# Is it possible that MongoDB overwrote my data/db folder

Tags: mongodb, database-backups, database

After restarting the mongod process, I lost all my database collections.
When in mongo shell typing `show collections` shows nothing. I was trying to use mongod --repair, but nothing happens. Mongod config file is ok, but it does not seem to be loaded by init script. However, when i use `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf` it does not solve the problem either. 
I am out of options. Is it possible that MongoDb overwrote my database? What options do I have to restore it?
I tried mongodump, but it has nothing to backup still

Below is the log from last attempt:

```
2015-12-07T00:25:04.179+0200 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] journal dir=/data/db/journal
2015-12-07T00:25:04.179+0200 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover : no journal files present, no recovery needed
2015-12-07T00:25:04.263+0200 I JOURNAL  [durability] Durability thread started
2015-12-07T00:25:04.263+0200 I JOURNAL  [journal writer] Journal writer thread started
2015-12-07T00:25:04.327+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=6403 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit 
2015-12-07T00:25:04.327+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-12-07T00:25:04.327+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled is 'always'.
2015-12-07T00:25:04.327+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2015-12-07T00:25:04.327+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-12-07T00:25:04.328+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] ** WARNING: /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/defrag is 'always'.
2015-12-07T00:25:04.328+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] **        We suggest setting it to 'never'
2015-12-07T00:25:04.328+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] 
2015-12-07T00:25:04.328+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.0.7
2015-12-07T00:25:04.328+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 6ce7cbe8c6b899552dadd907604559806aa2e9bd
2015-12-07T00:25:04.328+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build info: Linux ip-10-229-88-125 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 BOOST_LIB_VERSION=1_49
2015-12-07T00:25:04.328+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: tcmalloc
2015-12-07T00:25:04.328+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { config: "/etc/mongod.conf", net: { bindIp: "127.0.0.1", port: 27017 }, storage: { dbPath: "/data/db", journal: { enabled: true } }, systemLog: { destination: "file", logAppend: true, path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log" } }
2015-12-07T00:25:04.346+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017
```

Thanks.

Comment: It is unlikely MongoDB has overwritten your collections. Did you use the data directory `/data/db/journal`  before ? If yes, what files are in that directory ?

Comment: I just found that somehow dbpath was changed to new path with the previous one was var/lib/mongodb. However, now after changing Dbpath to /var/lib/mongodb i have this error:  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 98 Unable to create/open lock file: /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock errno:13 Permission denied Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating

Comment: How should I change permissions to fix it?

Comment: That error suggest that there is still an instance of mongod running using that directory. Can you kill all mongod processes and try again ?